# Best practices for switching ASP.NET MVC views based on user role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know the title of this question sounds like dozens that have been asked before, but I have a little bit of a twist on mine. The site in question does not use Membership roles, but instead has a custom security layer that evaluates granular rights associated with a given user. Based on information about the user, we determine whether a given user is a **vendor**, an **affiliate**, or a **customer**.

The issue I have is that these three functional roles each have materially different experiences in the UI. There is some overlap, but there is enough difference that doing security checks to manipulate the content of models and views is going to be cumbersome.

I'm assuming I can either:

1. Use MVC Areas to separate my application into functional units (I've never played with that), or
2. Stick with the logic in the model and a lot of `if...then` blocks in the view (or HtmlHelpers to hide that and make it look like I'm not putting logic in my view), or
3. Physically split the application into three applications, each running on their own host (customer.domain.com, vendor.domain.com, affiliate.domain.com).

That last option is by far the ugliest -- lots of duplicated code and I'd give myself the added task of traffic control application running on the www host.

I was hoping someone on SO had a similar scenario and could offer suggestions about how to deal with this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on scenario. If you have many shared views with minimal changes (for example lite customer, customer, premium customer) use conditions. If you have many completely different views (your example fits this category quite well - vendor, affiliate, customer) use areas. Or some mixture of those. From your description I think areas will serve you very well.

Physically separating into multiple applications is perfectly valid for extremly large projects, but I've got feeling that this is not your case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that helps. You're right - not large yet at all.